# how to execute a CA.dll during installation without installing it on the target machine

Tags: vb.net, wix

I am currently using a few executables (scripts) in my installer that are being called upon in different stages of the installation and/or de-installation process and are also placed on the target machine. I am currently trying to streamline this process since this implementation is not award winning and is causing a few problems since i am trying to . also the executables (scripts) are separate vb.net projects and not wix vb custom action projects. the executables I get from those projects are included in the installer and used as described above.

I want to accomplisch the following:

1) One WIX CustomAction project with multiple functions.

2) Call the CustomAction and start the required function.

3) Be able to call the CustomAction multiple times during installation and/or de-installation bud not installing it on the target machine.

The first two point are already working, however point the does not. I looked around on the internet and this site and found the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883150/wix-how-to-pack-exe-or-dll-to-use-only-during-installation) however when I implement it it doesn't work. I did the following:

```
 <Binary Id ="CustomAction" SourceFile ="$(var.C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wix test\test with multiple calls\bin\Debug\test with multiple calls.CA.dll)" />
 <CustomAction
Id="OnInstall"
BinaryKey="CustomAction"
DllEntry="CustomAction1"
Execute="deferred"
Impersonate="no"
Return="check"
/>
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="OnInstall" Before="InstallFinalize"> NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH </Custom>
```

however when I try to build it, I get the following error: Undefined preprocessor variable.

I looked into this error bud couldn't realy figure out what could causes it,
it is clear I need to define something however i don't know where and how.

all help is welcome

thanks in advance, 
F.Jansen

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe have a Preprocessor variable name called:

`C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wix test\test with multiple calls\bin\Debug\test with multiple calls.CA.dll`

So you either define a variable 
`<?define PathToCustomActionBin="C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wix test\test with multiple calls\bin\Debug\test with multiple calls.CA.dll)"`

And update you SourceFile in Binary element to `SourceFile=$(var.PathToCustomActionBin)`

Or just fix your code by removing `$(var.` from the beginning of SourceFile and `)` from the end.

Like:
`SourceFile="C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wix test\test with multiple calls\bin\Debug\test with multiple calls.CA.dll" />`

Comment: thanks for the reply, however none of this works. it does compile bud when using orca I can't see the file as part of the package. also the size of the .MSI remains the same which indicates nothing is added.

Comment: In Binary table check if you have your custom action dll, also check if you have your OnInstall custom action in CustomAction table in Orca. Also if it compiles maybe you should try and test the msi and look at the logs if the custom action is executing.

Comment: that's the thing, when compiled and I use orca too look in the Msi I can't find the custom action nor the Binary. also the file is nowhere to be seen

Comment: when i add the CA.dll as any other file with an component it does work on install. however it cant run on uninstall since it is then already deleted from the target machine. so it is realy neccesery to just add it in the package and run it from there. also when done this way i can see the binary as well as the custom action.

Comment: Is `<InstallExecuteSequence><Custom Action="OnInstall"...` under the Product element? Otherwise you might have the Custom action in a Fragment and not referenced in the product, hence not included in the final MSI.
If yes then you need to post more code to be able to see where the problem is.